# How to define different classes of offers for a gym or store?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

A friend of mine has asked me to create a management system for his gym.

Initially, the requirements were minimal, since he only offers a single training bundle of 30 training sessions, but then it turned out that he is going to move to a bigger place soon and he will likely want to implement different solutions for his customers, such as group workouts, training classes and so on. 
Since we still don't know yet what are the offers that he would like to add, we decided to keep the requirements minimal. However, I would like the system to be able to accommodate those changes eventually. Could you suggest me any Object oriented solutions to this problem?

Comment: The design of your domain heavily depends on the requirements. As long as this is not defined, there is no way to suggest an OOP solution. In general, Domain Driven Design is something that allot of people are doing right now, as it keeps the domain rules and classes all in one place, so I would recommend to read up something on DDD. But there is no "Gym Management Pattern" if you are asking that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: don't. Start with what is there and build it out from there. Do not implement things that you are not sure will exist in the future.

So currently an object with a `type`: `SINGLE_TRAINING_BUNDLE` and a description: `30 training sessions`. Add more types with different descriptions and work from there.

Make your business logic dependent on the type field until that becomes unwieldy. Etc.